# PostgreSQL: Convert Column names as Row with values

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

My sample table:

table_name

```
Code | Name | Location ---- (Table Column)
C001 | John | China
C002 | Joy  | Taiwan
B001 | Carl | Turkey
```

Result: The column will serves as row with its value.

```
Code     | C001
Name     | John
Location | China
```

I need sample query for postgreSQL just like in SQL -> STUFF function.

Comment: "SQL" (the query language) has no `stuff` function.

Comment: This has been answered many times: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+pivot+crosstab

Comment: Consider that all data in a column is expected to be of the same time.Your specific example shows all "varchar" data, but in general what you're asking for is not something that can be done without casting all data to the same type, varchar or json, etc.

Comment: Only select one value at a time. I just need to include "where" clause when execute the query

Comment: Does your table have multiple records in it?

Comment: @JoeLove, thanks for your attention on my question. But i check the comment of @ a_horse_with_no_name, and found the query i need. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT key, value
FROM (
  SELECT row_to_json (t.*) AS line
  FROM table_name t
) AS r
CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_each_text (r.line);
```

Reference [HERE](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/06/19/crosstab-pivot.html#how-to-unpivot-a-dataset)